# Golang regex to parse out repo name from git url

Tags: regex, go

I need a way of parsing out the repo name from a git repo url WITHOUT using a split function.

For example I want to be able to do the following

```
url := "git@github.com:myorg/repo.git"
repoName := parseRepoName(url)
log.Println(repoName)  //prints "repo.git"
```

Comment: Any particular reason not to use `strings.Split`?

Comment: @Ainar-G I know how to do it using a split, but I want to know how to do it parsing out with a regex. Any advantage to using a split versus a regex?

Comment: @TheJediCowboy: why do you want a more complicated solution for splitting a string? While something like `":[^/]+/(.*)"` is pretty simple, `string.Index` or `strings.Split` is downright obvious to the person reading the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not that much familiar with golang till days. May be you can go with replace instead of split. For example using the following pseudocode.

Make a regex `.*/` and then replace it with your string.

```
reg.ReplaceAllString(url, "")
```

This will replace anything before the last `/` and you'll have the `repo.git`

Answer (score 3):

Save yourself the trouble of using a regex where you don't need one and just use:

```
name := url[strings.LastIndex(url, "/")+1:]
```

Or if you are not sure that the url is a valid github url:

```
i := strings.LastIndex(url, "/")
if i != -1 {
    // Do some error handling here
}
name := url[i+1:]
```